# 'NativeReanimated' could not be found. Verify that a module by this name is registered in the native binary

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer

[This is my Code which is showing this error . Here I am trying to make a Drawer-navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMriX.png)

[This is the error showing , I am doing this in react-native.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYwMf.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might have missed some installation / setup steps for `react-navigation`.

Please check this section in the docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started#installing-dependencies-into-a-bare-react-native-project

If you have already installed the packages listed there (notably `react-native-reanimated`), perhaps you have not installed the native dependencies. This is important on iOS - run `npx pod-install` in your project root, and then build the app again (hot reload will not be enough).

Comment: The issue still remains after following these steps.